# Why doesn't this regex work as expected in Java?

Tags: java, regex

trivial regex question (the answer is most probably Java-specific):

```
"#This is a comment in a file".matches("^#")
```

This returns false. As far as I can see, `^` means what it always means and `#` has no special meaning, so I'd translate `^#` as "A '#' at the beginning of the string". Which should match. And so it does, in Perl:

```
perl -e "print '#This is a comment'=~/^#/;"
```

prints "1". So I'm pretty sure the answer is something Java specific. Would somebody please enlighten me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`Matcher.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) checks to see if the *entire input string* is matched by the regex.

Since your regex only matches the very first character, it returns `false`.

You'll want to use [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) instead.

Granted, it can be a bit tricky to find the concrete specification, but it's there:

- [`String.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) is defined as doing the same thing as `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`.
- [`Pattern.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) in turn is defined as `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()`.

  - [`Pattern.compile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) returns a `Pattern`.
  - [`Pattern.matcher()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) returns a `Matcher`
- [`Matcher.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) is documented like this (emphasis mine):

  > Attempts to match the *entire* region against the pattern.

Comment: This is the right answer, thank you. Is this documented somewhere? Because I cannot read this from the documentation of String.matches: "Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression." does not sound like what you described.

Comment: I've always understood "matches" to imply "the entire input", but I've added the full explanation (and how to find it) above.

Answer (score 2):

The `matches` method  matches your regex against the *entire* string.

So try adding a `.*` to match rest of the string.

```
"#This is a comment in a file".matches("^#.*")
```

which returns `true`. One can even drop all anchors(both start and end) from the regex and the `match` method will add it for us. So in the above case we could have also used `"#.*"` as the regex.

Comment: ...which will only work if the string doesn't contain any newlines, unless you prepend `(?s)` to your regex...

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your expectations:

```
"#This is a comment in a file".matches("^#.*$")
```

Now the input String matches the pattern "First char shall be `#`, the rest shall be any char"

---

Following Joachims comment, the following is equivalent:

```
"#This is a comment in a file".matches("#.*")
```

Comment: In this case, both anchors (`^` and `$`) are unnecessary, as they are implied by `matches()`.