# Regex repeated character (\\1 doesn't work)

Tags: java, regex, string, repeat

I'm currently trying to make a regex in Java that simply returns true if any repeated characters are present in the input string and false otherwise, with a regex as short as possible (for a code-golf challenge). I'm not very good at regexes, but I thought this would do the trick:

```
(.)\\1
```

Where `(.)` is any character and `\\1` is a reference to the match found in the first part of the regex.

However, if I try it for the input "`1223`", it doesn't work:

```
public static void main(String[] a){
     System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.matches("(.)\\1", "1223"));
}
```

This return false, while I'm expecting true because of the `22`.

Does anyone know how to fix the regex using the `java.util.regex.Pattern.matches`, or something shorter, since it's code-golf? ;)

[Here is an ideone for the test.](https://ideone.com/em4oPE)

Comment: `.matches` requires a full string match, use `".*(.)\\1.*"`. Or use yours with `Matcher.find()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, that's my problem! Thanks. If you want you can add it as an answer. I knew it had something to do with my misunderstanding of `.matches`..

Comment: `System.out.println(java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(.)\\1").matcher("1223").find());`

Comment: I'd rather close as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792067/3832970. It is a very frequent problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the answer either way.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I know of the codegolf-stackexchange.com, but this question was mainly about why my regex didn't work and golfing it was a bonus, not a requirement.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi what's the point of your comment? This is a concrete problem with regex and perfectly fine here.

Comment: @f1sh OP mentioned that it was for a codegolf challenge, so I suggested that.

Answer (score 3):

`Pattern.matches(regex, sequence)` returns whether the **whole** string corresponds to `regex`, not if a substring that does match exists.

For what you are trying to do, you can do one of two things:

1. Use the regex `".*(.)\\1.*"` instead
2. Use the `Matcher` class:

   ```
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(sequence).find(); 
   int start = m.start();  
   int end = m.end();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

[`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-) consumes the whole string: First the `.` matches "1", then `\\1` attempts to match "1" as the next character, and fails.

You have two options:

- Use [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), or
- Change your regex to `.*(.)\\1.*`

Explanation:

The second option now works because `.*` will first match the whole string, then it'll fail to match `\\1`, it backtracks char by char until the `.*` matched "1", then the `(.)\\1` will match the "22", and the final `.*` will match the rest of the string.